# Is it against the rules to post login credentials in a question?

Tags: discussion

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65425315/how-can-i-create-account-page-for-users-in-wordpress) where the author posted the login credentials to a website he/she wants to replicate.

It doesn't feel right to have someones login credentials in the question, but I don't think it's necessarily against any rules. **What should I do in such a situation?**

Another user already posted a comment, noting the author that is may not be a good idea to post login credentials in a question.

> I don't know if it's against any of the rules on this site, but posting login credentials just feels bad.

Is there anything else I should do? Maybe flag for moderation attention?

Comment: There are no rules against it. If users want to leak their login credentials or API keys, we really can't stop them. But we can try to clean up the damage after the fact.